# Insert jpg image in the margin of beamer slide

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, graphics

I am using the Goettingen theme (beamer). I want to insert a jpg file in the margin (bottom right) of the current frame. I also want the image to be semi-transparent. Please help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}      %for positioning
\usepackage{tikz}                           %for transparency

\newenvironment{reference}[2]{%                                            %
\begin{textblock*}{\textwidth}(#1,#2)                                      % creates the reference environment              
  \footnotesize\it\bgroup\color{red!50!black}}{\egroup\end{textblock*}}    %

\usetheme{Goettingen}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{reference}{108mm}{70mm}
\tikz\node[opacity=0.4]{\includegraphics{yourjpeg.jpg}};
\end{reference} 
\frametitle{Title}
Content 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The solution is based on the tetxpos and TikZ packages. It produces this:
[image]

you need to insert the location of you jpeg image and change the reference values according to its size. The beamer slide is 128*96mm. You may also need to scale your jpeg `\includegraphics[scale=<value>]`

If you instead want the jpeg to appear in every frame, then add this code in the preamble

```
    \setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}{
    \begin{reference}{108mm}{70mm}
    \tikz\node[opacity=0.4]{\includegraphics{yourjpeg.jpeg}};
    \end{reference}
    }
```

notice the `sidebar left` template. It must be on the opposite side with respect to where your navigation sidebar is, otherwise it will overwrite it.

Comment: Thank you all for your timely contributions, I used the solution from @dcmst and I am very impressed with the result. This is a great forum!

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable, and perhaps the only way to accomplish both transparency and absolute control over image position is to change the background image, even if only for a single slide:

```
\setbeamertemplate{background}
    {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{background.jpg}
}
```

Take a look at what I did with the university seal in my example in the bottom right corner:

[image]

Comment: this solution will not work for the OP because he uses goettingen which has a vertical sidebar. As far as I understand his question, he wants the image to appear inside the sidebar, while your code will put it outside of the sidebar.

Comment: The question is a bit ambiguous, but in that case, yes, your solution (using \setbeamertemplate{sidebar} (why _left_, by the way -- wouldn't that have to be _right_?) would probably be a better choice.

Comment: if you set it to right then the right template is overwritten and you lose the vertical navigation sidebar, author information, etc. If you set the sidebar opposite to the one you're actually using you can workaround this problem without having to completely rewrite the sidebar template. The image will still appear in the right sidebar because you set the position with textpos. 
You're actually cheating beamer, but it is an easier solution then rewriting the template.

Comment: I see what you mean now, that makes sense.